# Flutter -- Is there a better solution for searching for users

Tags: flutter, search

In my search_user.dart, I want the current user to see a list of possible matches every time they update their input in the text field. Now I'm afraid that I'm querying Firestore an uneccessary amount of times to do this and if I have upwards of a thousand users, I could potentially get a Firebase bill that's quite expensive. I would love to know if anyone has a better solution or knows of an extension/package that could aid me in this UI feedback.

This file also doesn't support username and/or name searching. And if anyone has a solution to that, I'd love to hear it!

```
// ---- search_user.dart ----

// method for updating Future<QuerySnapshot>? _searchResults
// I could be wrong, but I'm using the username from Provider instead of calling
// firebase in hopes that I don't make an unecessary read... 
void _search() {
    final userUsername =
        Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).user?.username;
    setState(() {
      _searchResults = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('username', isNotEqualTo: userUsername)
          .where('username',
              isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                  "@${_searchController.text.toLowerCase()}")
          .get();
    });
  }

// search text field widget
// to give the user a sense of feedback, im using the onChanged to render the list
// of users every time they add a letter. I feel this is better for the client but
// I fear that I'm making too many reads at a time and would love to know of a better
// solution. Im open to third party extensions or packages
Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _searchController,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search by username',
                hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                    color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color, size: 25),
                suffixIcon: Visibility(
                  visible: _searchController.text.isNotEmpty,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => _searchController.clear(),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.cancel,
                        color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color, size: 25),
                  ),
                ),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                _search();
              },
            ),
          ),
```

I have tried to limit the search to result only when the user clicks the search button, however, I felt that this UI feedback wasn't sufficicent enough for users who don't quite know the exact username they're looking for. And using onChanged seemed the only appropriate way of providing this kind of client feedback however, might be a poor choice when it comes time to read the users document from Firestore.

Comment: https://www.launchclub.io/blog/flutter-firestore-pagination-tutorial or https://codewithandrea.com/articles/firestore-pagination-list-view/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are better ways.

You listed 2 problems:

1. Not being able to search by name or username.
2. Unnecessarily calling the search method.

For problem 1, you can create a field in your Firestore document field called “searchTerms”, for example, containing a list of Strings with the possibles search terms for that doc. Then, when you create or update any of them, you update this list with possible values for the name and the username:

[image: searcTerms]

For problem 2, you can implement a debouncer. This allows the application to wait until the user has stopped typing for a specified duration before performing a search, thereby reducing the number of searches triggered:

```
import 'dart:async';


class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;
  Timer? _timer;

  Debouncer({
    required this.milliseconds,
  });

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer?.cancel();
    }
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  final _debouncer = Debouncer(milliseconds: 500);
  List<Widget> _searchResults = [];  

  void _onSearchChanged(String query) {
    _debouncer.run(() {
      setState(() {
        // Your search logic here
        // [..]
        var result = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('username', isNotEqualTo: userUsername)
          .where(ClientsDBFieldsNames.searchTerms,
            arrayContains: query);
          .get();
        // [..]
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Debouncer Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: _onSearchChanged,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Search',
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(_searchResult),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

P.S.:

1. Directly accessing Firestore from the UI is not a good practice. It's advisable to study design patterns and dependency inversion.
2. You can create a singleton Debouncer for the entire application to limit calls to Firestore. This can be done according to a function where you pass its ID, and the Debouncer determines whether or not it can execute based on established frequency and limits. This way, in case of an infinite loop, for example, you will be protected against receiving a much larger bill than necessary.